# Derivative of a matrix divided by its Frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have a function $f$ that takes $\textbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ as input and return $\textbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrix as output.

$$
\textbf{Y}=f(\textbf{X}) = \textbf{X} \frac{1}{||\textbf{X}||_F}
$$

where $||\textbf{X}||_F \in \mathbb{R}$ is the Frobenius norm of matrix $\textbf{X}$. What is the derivative of $\textbf{Y}$ with respect to $\textbf{X}$, i.e., what is $\frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial \textbf{X}}$?

---

This is my attempt:

First, set $a=||\textbf{X}||_F=\sqrt{\sum^m_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}x_{ij}^2}$, then tried to calculate $\frac{\partial a}{\partial \textbf{X}}$ myself as follows
$$
\frac{\partial a}{\partial x_{ij}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sum^m_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}x_{ij}^2}}\cdot 2x_{ij}=\frac{1}{a} x_{ij}
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial a}{\partial \textbf{X}} = \frac{1}{a}\textbf{X}
$$
Then calculate $\frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial a}$ as follows
$$
\textbf{Y} = \textbf{X} \frac{1}{||\textbf{X}||_F} = \frac{1}{a} \textbf{X}
\Rightarrow
\frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial a} = -\frac{1}{a^2}\textbf{X}
$$

I think
$\frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial \textbf{X}} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Using chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial \textbf{X}}= \frac{1}{a} + \frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial \textbf{X}} = \frac{1}{a} + \left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\textbf{X}\right)\left(\frac{1}{a}\textbf{X}\right) = \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{a^3}\left(\textbf{X} \textbf{X} \right) \ \ \ \text{ <-- I think this is wrong}
$$
I think I am doing **incorrectly** as $\textbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a non-square matrix, and $\frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial \textbf{X}} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

---

How should I calculate $\frac{\partial a}{\partial \textbf{X}}$ and $\frac{\partial \textbf{Y}}{\partial \textbf{X}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}  \def\d{\delta}   \def\L#1{\l^{-#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}   \def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}} \def\F{{\cal F}} \def\G{{\cal G}} \def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\e{\epsilon} \def\f{\phi}     \def\g{\gamma}   \def\h{\eta}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$A matrix-by-matrix gradient is a fourth-order tensor, so the use of tensors is unavoidable.

Towards that end, introduce the Frobenius $(:)$ and dyadic $(\star)$ products
$$\eqalign{
\f &= G:H \qiq \f = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n G_{ij}\,H_{ij} \\
F &= G:\H \qiq F_{kl} = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n G_{ij}\,\H_{ijkl} \\
F &= \G:H \qiq F_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{l=1}^n \G_{ijkl}\,H_{kl} \\
\F &= G\star H \qiq \F_{ijkl} = G_{ij}H_{kl} \\
}$$
and an identity tensor $\E$ which can be defined in terms of Kronecker deltas
$$\eqalign{
\E_{ijkl} &= \d_{ik}\d_{jl} = \begin{cases}
\o\quad{\rm if}\;\;i=k\;\;{\rm and}\;\;j=l \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
\E:B &= B:\E = B \quad \big({\rm identity\:relation}\big) \\
}$$
Next, we need to differentiate the Frobenius norm
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \|X\|_F \\
\l^2 &= \|X\|^2_F \;=\; X:X \\
2\l\:d\l &= 2X:dX \\
{d\l} &= \L1X:dX \\
}$$
Then we need to differentiate $Y$
$$\eqalign{
Y &= \L1X \\
dY &= \L1dX - \L2X\,\c{d\l} \\
 &= \L1\E:dX - \L2X\LR{\c{\L1X:dX}} \\
 &= \L1\LR{\E-Y\star Y}:dX \\
\grad{Y}{X} &= \L1\LR{\E-Y\star Y} \\
}$$
As expected the gradient is a fourth-order tensor.

Translating this into index notation
$$\eqalign{
\grad{Y_{ij}}{X_{kl}}
 \;=\; \frac{\E_{ijkl}-Y_{ij}Y_{kl}}\l
 \;=\; \frac{\d_{ik}\d_{jl}-Y_{ij}Y_{kl}}\l \\
\\
}$$

---

Another approach is to *flatten* the matrices into vectors
$$\eqalign{
y &= \vc Y,\quad x = \vc X,\quad \l = \|x\|_F \\
\grad{y}{x} &= \frac{I-yy^T}\l \qif
\grad{y_i}{x_k} = \frac{\d_{ik}-y_iy_k}\l \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\diff{\mathbf D}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$I think that these things are usually easiest expressed in terms of the *total differential* $\diff f$. If $f : A \to B$, then the total differential evaluated at $X \in A$ is the linear function $\diff f_X : A \to B$ best approximating $f$ at $X$; in particular, if $f$ is linear then $\diff f_X(H) = f(H)$. We will write $\diff[f(X)](H)$ to denote the differential at $X$ of $X \mapsto f(X)$ evaluated at $H$.

We will use the following facts:

1. The *chain rule* says that
   $$
     \diff[f\circ g]_X = \diff f_{g(X)}\circ\diff g_X.
   $$
2. *The derivative of an expression is the sum of the derivatives of its subexpressions*:
   $$
     \diff[f(X, X)] = \dot\diff[f(\dot X, X)] + \dot\diff[f(X, \dot X)].
   $$
   The dots indicate what is being differentiated; the undotted variable should be thought of as held constant. For example, if $(X, Y) \mapsto XY$ is a bilinear product,
   $$
     \diff[X^2](H) = \dot\diff[\dot XX](H) + \dot\diff[X\dot X](H) = HX + XH.
   $$
3. The differential of $f : \R \to \R$ is
   $$
     \diff f_x(h) = hf'(x).
   $$
4. The differential of $f : \R^n \to \R$ is
   $$
     \diff f_x(h) = h\cdot(\nabla f).
   $$
5. The Froebenius norm is just like the Euclidean norm of a vector, so we can verify that
   $$
     \diff\bigl[||X||_F\bigr](H) = H\bullet\frac X{||X||_F},
   $$
   where $\bullet$ is the Froebenius inner product.

These fact together let us easily evaluate the differential of $f(X) = X\frac1{||X||_F}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
  \diff\left[X\frac1{||X||_F}\right](H)
&= \dot\diff\left[\dot X\frac1{||X||_F}\right](H)
  + \dot\diff\left[X\frac1{||\dot X||_F}\right](H)
\\
&= H\frac1{||X||_F} - X\frac{\diff\bigl[||X||_F\bigr](H)}{||X||_F^2}
\\
&= H\frac1{||X||_F} - X\frac{H\bullet X}{||X||_F^3}.
\end{aligned}$$
If you want to the express $\diff f_X$ as some sort of matrix, that depends an several different conventions. At least in index notation, if we represent matrices as $(2,0)$-tensors then we can write
$$
  \left(\diff f_X(H)\right)^{ij} = \left(\diff f_X\right)^{ij}_{kl}H^{kl},\quad
  \left(\diff f_X\right)^{ij}_{kl} = \frac1{||X||_F}\delta^i_k\delta^j_l - \frac1{||X||_F^3}X^{ij}X_{kl}.
$$